# Want to install kitkat 4.4 on Samsung Star Pro (S7262)

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, rom-flashing, custom-roms, 4.4-kitkat

I want to install Kitkat 4.4 on my Samsung Star Pro S7262 (rooted). I could't find a solution by googling. If it is not possible or not available for my phone right now, please suggest me any other version which is greater than jellybean 4.1

Comment: There aren't many ROMs for that device at all. Your best bet is to search around XDA. I only found the Stock ROM myself http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2569046 but you may have more look if you keep searching. However, it doesn't have its own page on XDA so I doubt there is much development done for it to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

http://guidesdna.com/update-galaxy-star-pro-s7262-android-4-4-kitkat/

http://techbeasts.com/2014/02/17/update-galaxy-star-pro-to-android-4-4-2-kit-kat-custom-rom/

I am willing to try this on star pro. Not done yet although. Do it on ur own risk ;)

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference (please [edit] your question and do so). Otherwise your question ceases to be helpful in case the links die.

Comment: Mrigesh Raj Shrestha>>>> Have u tried it...? Does it work???

Comment: Not yet. It seems this guy's offering is working for few only. So I couldn't take the risk. It seems to work well for star pro mobiles that hasn't been updated to latest version provided in system update. My device is up to date so its prone to fail.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend trying to get in contact with some Samsung developer on XDA forums and request him to develop for the device.
There are less chances of this method working but this is the only thing u can do other than developing yourself.